# Open Word template, paste Excel data in and save

Tags: vba, excel, ms-word

I've got an Excel data range I need to be able to paste into a Word document template and save automatically using a macro from Excel.

Currently when it is run, it tells me the template file is already open/locked and I have to open a read only copy for it to continue.
It does create and save the word file but when I try open the saved word doc it says there are problems with the contents..

I've Googled a lot and think I'm close but if anyone can give me some pointers that would be appreciated.

```
Option Explicit

Sub CopyExcelDataToWord2()

Dim wdApp As New Word.Application
Dim wdDoc As Word.Document

Dim wsSource As Excel.Worksheet
Dim docWordTarget As Object
Dim SaveAsName As String
Dim customSavePath As String
Dim nameFile, WordName2
Dim ColRange As Range

Set wdDoc = wdApp.Documents.Open("C:\test\templ.dotx")
wdApp.Visible = True

   'Cell with the filename to save final doc as
   nameFile = Sheets("Form").Cells(70, 1).Value

'Gets the file path from cell and adds variable 'nameFile' value to the end
customSavePath = Worksheets("Form").Cells(57, 1).Value & "\" & nameFile & ".docx"

'sets the variable wsSource to the activesheet
Set wsSource = ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet

    Set ColRange = Sheets("Form").Range("A1:D54")
   'if no data is selected then exit sub
    If ColRange Is Nothing Then
        Exit Sub
    'sets variable WordName2 to the selected columns address
    Else
       'sets variable WordName2 to column Range
       WordName2 = ColRange.Address
    End If


'With word document make visible and select
With wdApp
    .Visible = True
    Set docWordTarget = .Documents.Open("C:\test\templ.dotx")
    .ActiveDocument.Select
End With

    'With excel workbook copy the column selected previously
    With wsSource
        .Range(WordName2).Copy
    End With
    'Paste data into word doc
    With wdApp.Selection
        .PasteExcelTable linkedtoexcel:=False, wordformatting:=False, RTF:=False
        .TypeParagraph
    End With

With wdApp
  'Save word doc in the custom save path
  .ActiveDocument.SaveAs Filename:=customSavePath
    .ActiveWindow.Close
    ' Kill the Object
    .Quit
End With

MsgBox "Exported To:" & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & (customSavePath)

Set docWordTarget = Nothing
Set wdApp = Nothing
    Application.CutCopyMode = False

End Sub
```

Comment: @user1875797 What do you want the modifications to be saved in the template (so that the template changes), or in a document file *derived* from the template?

Comment: Hi the template is just a blank document with a header and footer, I'd like to save it as a new word document which is in the customSavePath variable, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Try documents.add instead of documents.open

It will open an instance of the template, instead of the template itself

Answer (score 2):

First, you are getting a lock error because the instance of word is still running in the background and locking the file you are trying to re-open. You can verify that with the task manager. To avoid this error, you can either:

- kill the WinWord.exe process in the task manager
- use wdApp.documents.Add instead of .open

Or (best)

- Write a function that either gets the word application running in the background or if none, creates a new one. This is the best option IMO, because you will not have the risk to have many invisible Word processes running in the background.

  ```
  Private Function GetWordApp() As Word.Application

      On Error Resume Next

      Set GetWordApp = GetObject(, "Word.Application")

      If GetWordApp Is Nothing Then Set GetWordApp = New Word.Application

  End Function
  ```