# How to temporarily open a Word document and use it to copy-paste a range?

Tags: vba, excel

I have formatted cells that I wish to copy and paste into an html form.

- If I copy the contents to a Word document and paste them from there to an html form, it works.
- If I copy the contents directly from the spreadsheet into the html form, the formatting is lost.
- If the range is in the clipboard after copying from a Word document, I can paste it to the html form.

I need a way to copy the range to clipboard and retain the formatting. Since from Word it works, that's where I'm starting... but if there is another way...

I'm thinking of either an embed word file, or a hidden one.

Copy cell, paste there, select all and copy from there. Afterwards, close/discard it.

EDIT: Managed to get some code... but it worked, then stopped, then worked again... no idea why...

```
Sub TempDoc()

Dim WDApp As Word.Application
Dim WDDoc As Word.Document

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Set WDObj = Sheets("Text2Form").OLEObjects("WDOC")

WDObj.Activate
WDObj.Object.Application.Visible = False

Set WDApp = GetObject(, "Word.Application")
Set WDDoc = WDApp.ActiveDocument

    WDApp.Visible = False

Worksheets("Text2Form").Cells(12, 4).Copy
    WDApp.Selection.Goto What:=wdGoToLine, Which:=wdGoToLast
    WDApp.Selection.PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

WDApp.ActiveDocument.Content.InsertAfter vbNewLine

Worksheets("Text2Form").Cells(14, 4).Copy
    WDApp.Selection.Goto What:=wdGoToLine, Which:=wdGoToLast
    WDApp.Selection.PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

WDDoc.Content.Copy
WDDoc.Content.Delete

WDApp.Quit
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: Here's a push in the right direction: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32739715/open-word-template-paste-excel-data-in-and-save/32741075

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried right-clicking on the cell you wish to paste into, and clicking "Paste Special"?

Comment: Maybe I wasn't clear in the request: I have formatted cells that I need to copy to another place, one that, from excel (no matter what I do) won't go with the formatting. One way I found was to copy to a Word document and copy again there to paste in the form I need. What I need, is: I inserted a embedded word document that I want to copy the cells, paste there, copy from there to the clipboard. From there, I can just paste where I want.

Comment: What is the "other place" you need to copy your formatted text to?

Comment: It's a html form... or something of the sorts. I'm quite restricted on what I can use here... ie wont work with the site (restricted) and basically what I doing is a mouse macro with sendkeys... If I have in the clipboard a sendkeys "^v" works...

Comment: I see.  Now I understand the basis of the question.  Would you like a Macro to do this for you?  That would be a fairly simple solution.

Comment: Another option you could attempt is converting the Excel file into Google Sheets, and then copying and pasting the cell values from there.  That could potentially be an easy fix.

Comment: Google drive and others like that are also restricted... did managed to find some code... the odd thing is: it worked, then it stopped working... and today is working again...

Comment: That is quite odd.  Where did you find the code for the application?  Your HTML form sounds finicky and somewhat antiquated; do you mind me asking in what setting you are using this form?  There are more streamlined and user-friendly ways to do things like this, I believe.

Comment: Well... it's actually an email form... I cant use some direct mailing tool so... doing one myself... (Its a IBM Lotus iNotes)